# Elapsed Time to initial load take too long time?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, optimization, joomla

I have a news website used Joomla 2.5, and I'm beginner at Joomla and Apache server.

My problem is the first load take too long time and I tried all the ways I found it in the internet but nothing happening.

I know my problem goes around waiting time, but I don't know how I can fix it.
Please take a look on this report.

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/130605_X1_KVF/

http://gtmetrix.com/reports/alamnews.net/tQ4nGQ4Y

Thanks

Comment: It clearly says that `images` taking time to load.

Comment: During the first load, the cache is empty for your website, so it's a normal behaviour ; when you will visit it again, the cache will be filled with images, css and other stuff so it will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Check more closely with proper tools.

Check [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/). Also [YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/yslow/) provides lots of good tips.

[image]